# java division: Inconvertible types found: int

Tags: java, math, division

What's wrong with this code

```
int numOfPrimes=pf.FindNumPrimes(10000);
Double frequency=((Double)numOfPrimes)/10000d;
```

Says

> inconvertible types found   : int
>   required: java.lang.Double        Double
>   frequency=((Double)numOfPrimes)/10000d;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to autobox an `int` to a `Double` object, which is invalid.

Try:

```
int numOfPrimes=pf.FindNumPrimes(10000);

Double frequency=((double)numOfPrimes)/10000d;
```

Comment: that's an unnecessary cast and unnecessary boxing later on.

Answer (score 4):

Don't cast from primitives to wrapper types. Use lower-case `double`. And you don't need any casting in this case - the compiler does that automatically. The above can be simplified to:

```
int numOfPrimes = ...;
double frequency = numOfPrimes / 10000d;
```

You should almost never mix primitives with wrappers. And always prefer primitives (if possible). Use `Double.valueOf(..)` for conversion if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

`Double` is not a primitive type (like int, long, byte, etc). It's a class type. You can convert between double and Double using autoboxing but not between `int` and `Double`.

You should either declare `numOfPrimes` as `double` or do the cast to a `double` instead of a `Double`

```
double numOfPrimes=pf.FindNumPrimes(10000);
Double frequency=((Double)numOfPrimes)/10000d;
```

or

```
int numOfPrimes=pf.FindNumPrimes(10000);
Double frequency=((double)numOfPrimes)/10000d;
```

or without unnecessary casts:

```
double numOfPrimes = pf.FindNumPrimes(10000);
Double frequency= numOfPrimes /10000d;
```

or

```
int numOfPrimes = 10;
Double frequency = numOfPrimes /10000d;
```

Comment: these are some unnecessary casts.

Comment: Technically they are. Sometimes I prefer to make the intent explicit (in the case of 2). In the first version i was just lazy :).